# Multi-step time series forecasting

Tags: python, time-series, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, transformer-model

I have standard many-to-one different RNN models which I used for 1 target time series prediction using other time series as features. I use 14 as the input sequence length and 1 value which corresponds to the target time series at the time moment which corresponds to the end of the input sequence. I want to generalize this approach to have some forecast horizon and predict some predefined steps ahead. Then, I would construct my training batches as follows(with forecast horizon = 2 and in_seq_len = 4):

```
 . . ./. ./. . . . .
       |
/0 0 0 0/0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The next sample is shifted by one position:

```
  . . . ./. ./. . . .
          |
  0/0 0 0 0/0 0 0 0 0
```

As expected, I train the network to predict the sequence instead of just one value. My question is: How should I get the final predictions of the network if I got the output of my network of shape `[batch_size, forecast_horizon]`. The output tensors will be overlapping because the samples are shifted by one position as Pytorch RNN expects it to be. Should I take only the last samples as the network predictions? i.e. `[batch_size, -1]`

Comment: What is the point of forecasting multiple values if you're only using the last one in your final predictions? The output tensors will be overlapping, but in your design the input tensors are too since you're shifting, right? You could shift by `forecast_horizon` on every step.

Comment: Thank you for the idea. In this way how can I shift by `forecast_horizon` if the `number of samples` divided by `forecast_horizon` is not an integer?

Comment: Your data is discrete obviously, so the step size between two measurements is finite, I would just round the forecast horizon. If you want to forecast *2.5* steps , you can't, but what you can do is forecast *3* steps.

Comment: Do u mean that I have to adjust the `forecast_horizon` to be an integer divisor of the dataset size? i.e. if I have 505 data points, then I should take 5?

Comment: No, I am just saying `forecast_horizon` should be an integer. I mean, how would you do it otherwise. You can only forecast a *round* number of predictions, right?

Comment: Yes, it's true. But then, how can I construct my batches if, for instance, I have 505 data points and take 3 as the forecast horizon. In this case, I will have a problem with the last sample in a batch: it will contain only one target sample but I need 3 to stack my tensors in a batch.

Comment: Yes, you can ignore batches which are partially filled with the `drop_last` option whne defining your `torch.utils.data.DataLoader`.

Comment: Then, I won't have the corresponding prediction for that time moment which I will drop.

Comment: You will be dropping the entire batch, so no prediction/training for that batch

Comment: Yes, you're right. Then I won't have the predictions for the last batch at all. But I must have predictions for each time moment.

Comment: In that case you can stick with a stride of *1*, you shift the whole sequence with a single step every time. This way you can make a prediction, even for the last timesteps, whatever value `forecast_horizon` is set to.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I do. I just wondered if I'm doing right since there's a lot of repeating inputs to the model and I'm trying to find the way around.